# V-for loop method to not directly cause rendering

Tags: methods, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Every time i load the method loadComparison it returns needed data over different item in compare but when the Axios request is complete the v-for loop re-renders with the new information and causes a loop until no more new information has been received. How do i go about still allowing myself to iterate over "compare" without causing the loop to re-render causing spammy API requests

```
<v-flex v-for="(item, i) in compare" :key='i'>
  <span style="display: hidden;">{{loadComparison(item)}}</span>
```

method to poll API for different currency's that are stored in item.symbol

```
loadComparison: function(item) {
      var symbol = item.symbol;

        var webLink = 'https://api.coinMarketCap.com/v1/ticker/' + symbol + '/?convert=USD';
        axios.get(webLink)
          .then(response => {
               item.data.Volume = response.data[0]["example"];
               item.data.Change = response.data[0]["example"];
               item.data.Price = response.data[0]["example"];
               item.data.MarketCap = response.data[0]["example"]; 
          })
      }
```

Data is not displayed through this V-for loop that comes later to put together parts of data together to display from these requests that are made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion:

You can use another data property like `cacheItems` to save your search result. I prefer to using one dictionary (if each item has one unique key, that will be better, you don't need to do hash or else to generate one unique key).

Then the rest is simple, find out the result from the `cacheItems` to find out the result by the unique key.

Below is one sample (click Reload again and again to see the result)

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: 'abcdefghijklmn'.split(''),
    cacheItems: {},
    reloadCount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    reload: function () {
      this.reloadCount++
      let index=1
      console.log(this.items)
      this.items.forEach((item)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          let newValue = item + item + this.reloadCount
          this.$set(this.cacheItems, item, newValue)
        }, 300*index++)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="reload()">Reload</button>
  <p v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{cacheItems[item] || item}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, simply exit the function earlier if the axios request has already been run for the item before.

```js
loadComparison: function(item) {
  var symbol = item.symbol;

  if (typeof item.previouslyRequestedSymbol === "undefined") {
    // first time the request is happenning for this item
    item.previouslyRequestedSymbol = symbol;
  } else if (item.previouslyRequestedSymbol === symbol) {
    return; //exit before making request
  }

  // axios ...
}
```